# I destroyed my .iml file. Any way to recover?

Tags: intellij-idea

I had a brilliant idea that involved updating my project in terminal by using

"jar uf QuizEngine.iml QuizEngine.iml"

Now I cant access my project directories or packages except through tabs.
Ill show a pic to so you can see what I'm seeing. Its not big deal but ide like everything to be as it should.[Check out my JDK here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKMeP.png)

My question is how can I reverse the damage done? Or what is the damage I did so that I can fix it?

Comment: If anybody else has this problem. Just reimport your maven if you are using that framework. If your not using that framework then I hope somebody who knows stuff answers.

Comment: I would suggest to delete `*.iml` files (if any) and `.idea` directory and reimport project.